# Rspec validation error causing a test to fail (but it's my intention to have a validation error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Rspec

```
    context "has non ascii characters" do 

        it "will not call get_imdb" do 
          expect_any_instance_of(Celebrity).not_to receive(:get_imdb)
          FactoryGirl.build(:imdb_celebrity, first_name: "Sæthy")
        end

      end
```

model:

```
def celebrity_status

    if full_name.ascii_only?
      get_imdb  ## << -- returns string or nil
    end

   ###  If get_imdb returns nil (or isn't called), record is not valid

end
```

Validation fails if get_imdb returns nil or isn't called. My problem is that I'm trying to test the ascii characters portion of the method, but by doing that - my validation is failing and giving me a "Validation Failed" error in the console when running Rspec tests.

But that's what I want to happen... I want the validation to fail.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By itself, a model validation failure should not raise an exception. You may be attempting to save the record, which would case `save` to fail, and might raise an exception if called via `save!` or `create!`.

You can test whether the model is valid by calling `valid?`

```
expect(celebrity.valid?).to be false
```

It is also useful to check the error hash to see that it has the expected contents:

```
celebrity.valid? # => false
expect(celebrity.errors[:my_error]).to equal "my error message"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your code on having exceptions, you should use Rspec's `raise_error`matcher:

```
expect { 3 / 0 }.to raise_exception
```

More info here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher

Comment: A validation failure should not raise an exception.